# WPF Application - Ways to store a word list?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm attempting to develop an application in C#/WPF to aid in studying Spanish vocabulary.  Right now I'm simply reading in the vocabulary from a .txt file (the data is simple - a Spanish word and it's corresponding English word separated by a : ) and loading it into a Dictionary.

This works fine for a limited amount of data, but I have a feeling once I begin to include a larger scope of data (different verbs, vocabulary from specific chapters etc.) this could begin to get really ugly - I am wondering if anyone could lead me in the direction of a more elegant or efficient way to load and manage this data. Thanks.

Adam Davis

edit: if you want to take a look (the .txt and .exe must be in the same directory for the program to function properly)

http://www.scoperesolution.org/SpanishTutoring.exe

-http://www.scoperesolution.org/words.txt

Comment: Please tell us more about how you're using the file. Do you read the whole thing in at startup? Do you display one entry at a time? How do you present the dictionary to the user? Do you give them a word at random, or a list of words? How is the list of words shown to the user determined?

Comment: Jeff: Currently the program works with three different varities of verbs.  The .txt  file contains a complete list of all of the verbs and is read into the program - based on the selection of the user, only a certain subset of these verbs is loaded into the Dictionary to be used in the window.  From there, one random word is displayed and the user translates to the opposite language. When they get the answer right, a new random word is displayed. Recent words are put into a list to avoid displaying the same word again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a serverless database like [MS Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) or [sqlite](http://sqlite.org).

Comment: guillermooo: Excellent :) I had not heard of serveless databases' before - this looks very interesting/promising.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a good bit of data that will continually grow, why not give it a database backend?  I'm sure Sql Express would probably do just fine for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The direction for this type of thing should be "databases", such as MySQL.

First, they are professionally build for loading and searching speed, second, they'll give you way more flexibility. You can then search your vocabulary list for specific word type (verbs, nouns etc) and such. You should browse the web for some tutorials on databases that applies to C#/WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the data in .xml file(s) may be a good intermediate solution until the data become really big. Using LINQ to XML, you can easily read/load/update data and does not involve installing any new component or database.